# setVideoSize() crashes with high resolutions

Tags: android, video, android-camera, video-capture, video-processing

I would like to give the users an option to set different resolutions.

I've tried this solution

```
camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P);
....
....
mCamera.unlock();
recorder.setCamera(mCamera);
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);
```

It worked perfectly: nice quality and everything...

When I set it to

```
camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
```

with **FLASH on**, the video came out with greenish and some other weird colors.

I read online and people said it is because QUALITY_480P is probably not supported on my phone.  Ok, it makes senses.

Therefore, I started working on the different solution, so I've tried....

```
recorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
```

It worked great,

but the video looked VERY ugly.

Next, I checked for a supported video list.

```
List<Size> GetSupportedVideosResolutions =  params.getSupportedVideoSizes();
```

Resolution: 1280x720 is in the list, so

I've tried to set the following:

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setVideoSize(1280,720);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
```

It gave me a RuntimeException error.

The question is

**Why can't it let me set the higher resolutions that are available on the phone?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you.

Edit: added error log

```
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at test.com.VideoActivity.prepare_StartRecorder(VideoActivity.java:1009)
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at test.com.VideoActivity.Recorder_Start_Stop(VideoActivity.java:1102)
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at test.com.VideoActivity$6.onClick(VideoActivity.java:246)
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4489)
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:104)
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18803)
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
04-18 17:40:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(30191):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Since 720p is 1280x720, what were you expecting different from your last block of code compared to the first block of code that you said worked fine? IOW, if you want 1280x720 output, you already have working code for that. Beyond that, we cannot help you with an exception unless you post the stack trace and indicate what lines in that stack trace correspond to what lines in your code in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I like to give the users the option to choose different resolutions.  720P was the hard code.  720P may not be supported on another device.  Also, I mentioned that there was an issue with 480P with flash on.  I could try 1920x1080 and same error.

Comment: Which device are you testing?

Comment: Galaxy Note 2 Android 4.1.1 and 4.3, but it should not matter since I checked for the supported list first.  Thanks

Comment: That's a wrong assumption: Samsung devices too have camera-API related bugs and limitations.

Comment: You eventually call `MediaRecorder.start()`, which fails. Most likely, some parameters you set, are incompatible with 720p recording. These could be frame rate, scene, focusing, or something else. You may choose to expose more code of your **VideoActivity** - maybe somebody came across these incompatibilities before.

Answer (score 3):

I figured what the problem was.  This may help someone else.
I ended up with:

```
camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P);
recorder.setVideoSize(1280, 720);   //NEEDED or it will crash
```

Code:

```
camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P);
....
....
mCamera.unlock();
recorder.setCamera(mCamera);
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);
recorder.setVideoSize(1280 720);  //NEEDED or it will crash
....
...
```

//or

```
CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P);
recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);
recorder.setVideoSize(1920, 1080);  //NEEDED or it will crash
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: Iam1414's answer IS CORRECT.

I've been at this all day and as ridiculous as it seams, his technique works.

I was attempting to record in 4k(3840 x 2160), I was positive the device had the ability too, but It kept limiting me to 1080 and would crash on anything higher. 
The solution was as Iam1414 mentioned.

> -set the profile
>   -set the video size

```
profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_2160P);
recorder.setProfile(profile);
recorder.setVideoSize(3820, 2160);  //NEEDED or it will crash
```

Unfortunately setting the profile locks me in at encoding H264 and hasn't allowed me to set my encoder to my H265 encoder after. So hopefully there's a workaround for that as well.

Iam1414, Thank you. I'd vote you up if I had the rep   :)

Edit: This is a very strange error. Seams as though I no longer need to use the workaround. I'm able to record in 2160p simply by using the matching profile. I will investigate further if it continues to be an issue.